# Compose navigation

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

i have started to learn compose navigation and facing below issue , can you please suggest recommended way to solve below issue.

consider animal Screen and animal detail screen. i am using deeplink to launch animal screen(Deeplink has route for Animal Screen and parameter(name = animal name)). so what i want to achieve is launch animal screen using deeplink and if parameter (name = animal name) is not null lunch animal detail screen immediately from  animal screen.

Can someone guide me here ,thanks

Comment: Please include some code snippets that you are working with

Comment: There are tons of examples on compose navigation - the one provided by the android team [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) and other navigation libraries made by the community [link to a list](https://proandroiddev.com/the-state-of-navigation-in-jetpack-compose-cc13eb6ac3d9)

Comment: It seems your deep link is on the wrong screen - if you want to immediately link to the animal detail screen, then your deep link should be on that screen. That's the whole point of a deep link.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Agreed , but because of some restriction i can not go directly to animal detail screen. i have to open animal screen and then check parameter then launch animal detail screen.

Comment: That's the wrong way to approach the problem entirely. Please explain what "some restriction" means as part of your question.